# Create artificial argv array for legacy parent class accepting main-like arguments in the constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, legacy-code

I am struggling with the legacy code (refactoring scheduled, but I need to use it now) that has the devicedrivers designed to accept `(argc, argv)` arguments for its constructors. The base class that I have to use, and for now I cannot change it, looks like this:

```
class LegacyDriver
{
public:
  LegacyDriver(int argc, char** argv)
  {
    if (argc < 3)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("nope");
    }
    // some logic with the arguments interpretation
    int var1 = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int var2 = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << "config: " << var1 << ", " << var2 << "\n";
    // etc ...
  }
  virtual ~LegacyDriver() = default;
  // + some public interfaces, not important ...
};
```

Then my new driver that has to extend this class, needs to somehow pass that `argc, argv` args down to the base class. So far my colleagues were just playing along:

```
class MyNewDriver: public LegacyDriver
{
public:
  MyNewDriver(int argc, char** argv): LegacyDriver(argc, argv)
  {}
  ~MyNewDriver() override = default;
};
```

but this design is clearly not sustainable (e.g. difficult for testing) and I would like to at least provide a meaningful constructor to the new driver, like:

```
  MyNewDriver(int param1, int param2): LegacyDriver(somehowTransformThemIntoArgcArgv)
  {}
```

I can't use additional `MyNewDriver` private fields for that, because parent class has to be constructed before.
I thought about the hack like this, with the strings and vector in the global scope:

```
namespace {
std::string hackyProgramName = "Driver";
std::string hackyVar1;
std::string hackyVar2;
std::vector<const char*> hackyArgv;
auto constructArgv = [](int var1, int var2)
{
  hackyVar1 = std::to_string(var1);
  hackyVar2 = std::to_string(var2);
  hackyArgv = std::vector<const char*>({hackyProgramName.c_str(), hackyVar1.c_str(), hackyVar2.c_str()});
  return const_cast<char**>(hackyArgv.data());
};
}
class MyNewDriver: public LegacyDriver
{
public:
  MyNewDriver(int argc, char** argv): LegacyDriver(argc, argv)
  {}
  MyNewDriver(int param1, int param2): LegacyDriver(3, constructArgv(param1, param2))
  {}
  ~MyNewDriver() override = default;
};
```

But it just looks so ugly, and `argv` vector is invalidated with every new instance of my driver.

Is there a better way to do this? Preferably with single lambda.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike but the base class is initialized first, before `MyNewDriver` privat members.

Comment: How about using [base-from-member idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member), move the new driver params to this new base-member class and extract the argc/argv from it on construction of the `LegacyDriver`?

Comment: Why not use composition instead of inheritance ? `MyNewDriver` can have a `unique_ptr<LegacyDriver>` member and initialiaze it after converting the arguments to the proper argc, argv. This assumes `LegacyDriver` does not have too many methods you'd like to expose via `MyNewDriver` (because it will require a lot of duplication).

Comment: How about: write a ```MyNewDriver``` constructor that takes ```std::pair< int, char** >``` and calls the base class constructor with that.  Write a private method like ```constructArgv``` that returns a ```vector<string>``` and wrap that in another method to convert the vector into the pair.   The pointer in the pair would only have a lifetime until the end of the statement, but that's long enough to call the base class constructor.

Comment: O, that `base-from-member-idiom` is interesting, thanks! Comment about composition over inheritance also makes sense, I will think about those solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you move a vector, pointers into it are still valid. So you can construct the argv vector first then move it to a member:

```cpp
class ArgsHolder {
    std::vector<std::string> string_storage;
    std::vector<char*> argv_storage;
public:
    /*explicit(false)*/ ArgsHolder(std::vector<std::string> v) : string_storage(std::move(v)), argv_storage(string_storage.size() + 1) {
        // Remember the +1 for the nullptr at argv[argc]
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < string_storage.size(); ++i)
            argv_storage[i] = string_storage[i].data();
    }
    char** argv() noexcept { return argv_storage.data(); }
    int argc() noexcept { return argv_storage.size() - 1u; }
};

class MyNewDriver: public LegacyDriver
{
  ArgsHolder args;
public:
  MyNewDriver(int argc, char** argv): LegacyDriver(argc, argv)
  {}
  MyNewDriver(ArgsHolder args): LegacyDriver(args.argc(), args.argv()), args(std::move(args)) {}
  MyNewDriver(int param1, int param2)
   : MyNewDriver(ArgsHolder({ "Driver", std::to_string(param1), std::to_string(param2) }))
  {}
  ~MyNewDriver() override = default;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you must maintain a valid `argv` array and the action is to do before constuction of `LegacyDriver`, you can inherit of a class before.

```cpp
class PreDriver {
protected:
    PreDriver( int var1, int var2 ) {
        hackyVar1 = std::to_string( var1 );
        hackyVar2 = std::to_string( var2 );
        hackyArgv = std::vector<const char*>{"Driver", hackyVar1.c_str(), hackyVar2.c_str()};
    };
    constexpr int  argc()const     { return 3; }
    char**  argv() { return const_cast<char**>(hackyArgv.data()); }
private:
    std::string hackyVar1;
    std::string hackyVar2;
    std::vector<const char*>  hackyArgv;
};

class MyNewDriver : private PreDriver, public LegacyDriver {
public:
    MyNewDriver( int param1, int param2 ) : PreDriver(param1,param2), LegacyDriver( this->PreDriver::argc(), this->PreDriver::argv() ) {}
    ~MyNewDriver() override = default;
};
```